# How to calculate error in successive over relaxation for PDE?

Tags: finite-difference, c++

I am trying to solve the Poisson equation numerically using the FDM method in C++. But I have a little confusion with the iterative process. I understand that the number of iterations should go until the solution converges, but how to calculate if the error is greater/less than the tolerance level? Here is a small piece of code I tried in C++ but it is flawed. I checked some other codes posted online and some has calculated the average of the residual values in a matrix and checked accordingly. I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me with the concept.

```
void calculate_voltage(){
    voltage_initialization();   //creating a matrix V and initilizing with Dirchilet's boundary condition
    double tolerance = pow(10,-5);
    bool done = true;
    int itr = 0;
    double pi = 3.14;
    double t = cos(pi/nx) + cos(pi/ny);
    double omega = (8 - sqrt(64 - 16*pow(t,2)))/(pow(t,2));  //relaxation parameter
    
    while(done == true){
        itr ++;
        for(int i = 1;i<nx-1;i++){
            for(int j = 1;j<ny-1;j++)
            {
                double vv = (V[i-1][j] + V[i+1][j] + V[i][j-1] + V[i][j+1] + step_size_ * source[i][j])/4.0; 
                double R = vv - V[i][j];     //residual for SOR
                if(abs(R) <= tolerance){done = false;}        //to check if the correction converges or not
                V[i][j] = V[i][j] + omega* R;           //new V
            }
     
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you are doing here is basically if at any point the residual is less than tolerance, stop. You should use norm of the residual vector as an indicator. I guess easiest for you would be max residual or l2-norm of the residual.

Comment: I would suggest that you also add a "pessimistic" stop criterion to your code. The most common would be maximum number of iterations allowed.

Comment: @nicoguaro you mean without calculating the tolerance?

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas I referred to a code posted online and took the average of the residuals over the loop. I should create a residual vector and check the norm too.

Comment: No, you do both. The idea is to obtain convergence, but if you don't in the number of iterations given, you stop.

Comment: @nicoguaro Oh yeah, I did that. It worked. Thanks:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're solving the linear poisson equation $Ax = b$ I'd just check that the L2-norm of the residual vector illustrates convergence. I think the best thing to do is to calculate the initial norm $\rho_0 = ||b||_2$ and then have two tolerances, one relative ($\epsilon_r$) and one absolute ($\epsilon_a$) and you would terminate if either of them is satisfied. So if $\frac{\rho_i}{\rho_0} < \epsilon_r$ or if $\rho_i < \epsilon_a$ where $\rho_i = ||b - Ax_i||_2$. You could also use the max value of the residual to check (the infinity norm), but the most commonly used ones is the 2-norm, and this extends nicely to GMRES and other krylov solvers. regarding actual values, I'd say try an initial absolute tolerance of $1e-14$ and relative of $1e-12$ and see if that works. You can also plot convergence as a function of iterations which may be instructive.

Comment: Thank you. I checked the L2-norm and it worked. The convergence is fast too.